# jQuery on click change large image

Tags: jquery, image, click

I am trying to change the large image when you click the thumbnail

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function(){                
                 $id = $(this).attr("id");
                 $("#large-img img" . $id).addClass("active");      
                 return false;
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="large-img">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="" title="" id="yes" style="display: none;"/>        
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" id="no" style="display: none;"/>
</div>

<div id="thumbnails">
            <a href="#" id="yes">
                <img src="1_small" alt="" title="" width="76" height="76"/>
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="no">
                <img src="2_small.jpg" alt="" title="" width="76" height="76"/>    
            </a>
</div>
```

This is my old code but you cant fade it. I want to achieve the same sort of thing.

```
$('#thumbnails a').click(function(){
                $('#large-img').css('background-image', 'url(' + $img + ')');
                $('#medium-img').css('background-image', 'url(' + $img + ')');              
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: `$("#large-img img" . $id)` is not valid Javascript. Also, you have multiple elements with the same `id` on your page, which is never a good idea.

Comment: i too agree multiple elements with same id is not good practice!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function(){                
                 var id = $(this).attr("id");
                 $('#large-img').find('#'+id).addClass("active");      
                 return false;
            });
```

Comment: $('#large-img').find(".active").fadeOut().end().find('#'+id).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id, but you could certainly overload the title or name of the `a` elements. Then you just need a `#` sign and to use the right string concatenator for Javascript.

*Spoiler alert*

JS:

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                
    id = $(this).attr("name");
    $("#large-img img#" + id).addClass("active");      
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="large-img">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="" title="" id="yes" style="display:none;"/>        
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" id="no" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <a href="#" name="yes"><img src="1_small" alt="" title="" width="76" height="76"/></a>
    <a href="#" name="no"><img src="2_small.jpg" alt="" title="" width="76" height="76"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Since `ids` are unique, you don't have to bother with `"#large-img img#" + id`. By itself, `"#" + id` is sufficient.

Comment: @Frédéric too right, but I was trying to avoid making any more changes to the OP code. Since you mention it, just adding 'active' to the className will probably not help unless that class uses `!important` or OP stops using inline styles.

Comment: That doesn't work, firebug says the html doesn't change. Just to put things in perspective (sp?) this is what I originally had but there is no way for me to fade the old background image out and then fade the new one in. look below for code

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$("#large-img img#" + id).addClass("active");
```

Comment: What does '.' do in Javascript?